# How to center list menu item without text adding an extra line

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, centering

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but I can't seem to get it to work.  All I want is to add text in the middle of the list item (see code) however it creates an extra line and makes the row bigger.  I tried using the  tag but it doesn't work. How can I add the text to be centered without changing the row size?

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <style>
       .ui-icon-myicon:after {
          background-image: url("http://people.mozilla.org/~shorlander/files/australis-linux-svg-test/images-linux/toolbarButton-bookmark.svg");
       }
       .ui-icon-myicon2:after {
          background-image: url("http://forum.librecad.org/images/gear.png");    
       }
       .inlineIcon {
         display: inline-block;
         position: relative;
         vertical-align: middle;
         margin-right: 6px;
       }
    </style>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
       <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
           <h1>My page</h1> 
       </div>   
       <div role="main" class="ui-content">
           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
               <li data-icon="myicon"><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon-myicon2 ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Center this text</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div> 
       <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
          <h1>My page footer</h1>
       </div> 
   </div>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `text-align: center` to center align the text.
2. Set the extra icon to `display: block` and use the `ui-btn-icon-left` class to align left.

```css
li.x-center > a.ui-btn {
    text-align: center;
}
li.x-center > a > span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-icon="myicon" class="x-center">
        <a href="#"><span class="ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-myicon2"></span>Center this text</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y84936yt/3/)

Comment: @Salaman-A Almost forgot, what if i want to add text next to the image? I've been trying for the past hour but I cannot get it to align. For example I would like to have the following IMG text1 Centered Txt IMG text 2. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

There is a better solution than adding spans. Copy jQuery Mobile button's CSS, that are used for icons. Do the changes you want to them. Of course, add a custom class to `a` tag.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wkq1gjxu/).

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="ui-icon-myicon">Center Text</a>
</li>
```

jQuery Mobile uses `:after`, use `:before` for your left side icon.

```css
.ui-icon-myicon:before {
    content:"";
    left: .5625em;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #666;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background-image: url("http://forum.librecad.org/images/gear.png");
}
```

To center text, follow CSS hierarchy to override default settings.

Thanks to **ezanker** for his valuable input. Adding `padding: 40px` makes center alignment just perfect!

```css
.ui-listview > li > a.ui-btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px; /* see ezanker's comment below */
}
```

Comment: Your answer great, plus 1! You just need to equalize the left and right padding on the anchor to get true centering of the text: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wkq1gjxu/1/,  .ui-listview>li>a.ui-btn {text-align: center; padding-left: 40px;}

Comment: @ezanker and ciccolina Thank you both =D

Comment: @speedracer2003 :) just a side note, you don't really need all those spans and extra classes when you can use css only.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="text-align:center"` to your `<a>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<style>
   .ui-icon-myicon:after {
      background-image: url("http://people.mozilla.org/~shorlander/files/australis-linux-svg-test/images-linux/toolbarButton-bookmark.svg");
   }
   .ui-icon-myicon2:after {
      background-image: url("http://forum.librecad.org/images/gear.png");    
   }
   .inlineIcon {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 6px;
   }
</style>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
   <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
       <h1>My page</h1> 
   </div>   
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
           <li data-icon="myicon"><a href="#" style="text-align:center;"><span class="ui-icon-myicon2 ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Center this text</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div> 
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <h1>My page footer</h1>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The text is centered, however the left icon is also centered.  Is there a way to keep the icon aligned to the left and just the text be centered?

Comment: @speedracer2003 Ohhhh, I see-- _just_ the text. You could move your icon to the outside of the `<a>` tag, like so: